# Notification Popup on button press using Ajax/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm currently making a site that includes notifications, but I'm not too sure how to show them on button press. Something like "Show Weather" will show the notification somewhere in the bottom corner.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8pEd.png

How hard would it be able to do? Is it actually possible?

Comment: First try to find a solution your self. Then drop some code that you have tried. After, We all will help you to solve it. :D

Comment: thw question is not clear, how do u want your notification to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to show the Weather by clicking a button. Using this Plugging --- http://simpleweatherjs.com/

**HTML**

```
<div id="weather"></div>
<input type="submit" id="Show" value="Current Weather" />
```

**JQUERY**

```
// Docs at http://simpleweatherjs.com
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#weather").hide();

  $.simpleWeather({
    location: 'Nicosia, CY',
    woeid: '',
    unit: 'f',
    success: function(weather) {
      html = '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i> '+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
      html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
      html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li>';
      html += '<li>'+weather.wind.direction+' '+weather.wind.speed+' '+weather.units.speed+'</li></ul>';

      $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
});

$("#Show").click(function(){
  $("#weather").show();
});
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/LW3S9/4/

**And here is Demo with a popup using Jquery UI.**

http://jsfiddle.net/LW3S9/5/

So you will need Click functions and if something Specific like Weather its worh using a Plugging.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to display.

Use `click()` for the button press event.

```
$("button_reference").click(function(){
   // do your notification-related stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use click event to show the popup and if you need the notification in some animated way , you can use jQuery Animated

http://jsbin.com/dadiz/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can be able to display it with the help of `.click()` function which is an inbuilt function  in jquery.

```
$("the_id").click(function(){
 //your stuff here
});
```

Find more information about `.click()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/click/).